# Type erasure into a void*

Tags: c++, type-erasure

I'm seeking help in validating the correctness of the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

// Implementing a kind of 'reference' to any functor with a void(void) call signature
struct FunctionView {
    template<class F> 
    static void function_caller_prototype(void *functor) 
    {
        auto f = reinterpret_cast<F *>(functor);
        (*f)();
    }

    void (*function_caller) (void *);
    void *functor;

    template<class F> FunctionView(F *f): 
        function_caller{function_caller_prototype<F>}, 
        functor{const_cast<void *>(reinterpret_cast<const void*>(f))} {}

    void operator() () const 
    {
        function_caller(functor);
    }
};

void foo() 
{
    std::cout << "Calling foo" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    auto lambda = [&argc]() { 
        std::cout << "Calling lambda with argc " << argc << std::endl;
    };

    FunctionView cb_foo(foo);
    FunctionView cb_lambda(&lambda);

    cb_foo();
    cb_lambda();

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I can tell, the reinterpret_cast should not pose any problem, because the stored functor object is reinterpreted back to it's original type when being used inside the function_caller_prototype function template. void* has no alignment requirements and there is no data being allocated, copied or moved. I'm also casting away the constness of the original functor but that is also restored in function_caller_prototype. Despite the FunctionView::operator() is a const member function, the functor's operator() might not be const and do modifications on itself but that should not be a problem.

Am I missing something or is this code totally OK as I suspect?

Building it with different compilers and running tests with address sanitizer. No issues were detected.

Comment: why not use `std::function<void(void)>` ?

Comment: What does this thing do that a plain `F*` doesn't?

Comment: Let's say one would want to avoid memory allocations or vtable creation involved with std::function and would like to use this as a function parameter where a function would receive another function. Doing this without declaring such functions as templates to increase compilation times.
I understand that this issue is thin ice in terms of wheel reinventing and has questionable use-cases but let's put that aside and for the fun of it, argue about the type cast being correct or not.

Comment: It is not valid to cast a pointer-to-function to `void*`. The two are allowed to have different sizes (though in practice, they have the same size on all modern compilers because POSIX and Windows API require such casts). I suppose you could store something like a union of `void*` and `void(*)()` to work around this.

Comment: You seem to be reinventing a special case of [`function_ref`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p0792r10.html)

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was trying to achieve. Many thanks!